# MFC get modal dialog list

Tags: c++, unit-testing, user-interface, mfc, modal-dialog

I am working on unit test with MFC. My software is a SDI.

I have 2 threads : the first one is the graphic thread and the second one a unit test procedure which reproduce a user behavior. 
It is working well when there isn't modal dialog, I use SendMessage (to simulate click on button, or change text, etc.) which is blocking until the message has been treated so I haven't any sync issue.

But when the button opens a Modal CDialog I can't use SendMessage because the unit test thread is going to be blocked as long as the modal dialog is opened. So I use PostMessage and Sleep. And now my problem is to get the pointer of the current opened CDialog.

Here is the code of the unit test

```
bool UnitTestBoite()
{
   // Here I am in unit test thread
   CFrameWnd *pMainFrame = (CFrameWnd *)AfxGetMainWnd();
   // Post Message to notify the button ID_INSERER_BOITE is clicked
   pMainFrame->PostMessageW(WM_COMMAND, MAKELONG(ID_INSERER_BOITE, 0), 0);
   // In the handler of ID_INSERER_BOITE
   // there is something like CDialog dlg(pMainFrame, IDD_BASE_BOITE); dlg.DoModal();
   Sleep(1000);
   UINT myModalTemplateId = IDD_BASE_BOITE;
   ...
```

To get modal dialog pointer I tried :

```
CWnd* pChild = pMainFrame->GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
while (pChild != nullptr)
{
    // Retrieve template ID
    UINT nResourceId = GetWindowLong(pChild->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_ID);
    if (nResourceId == myModalTemplateId )
        break;
    pChild = pChild->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT);
}
if (pChild == nullptr)
    return false;
```

or

```
HWND hwndForeGround = ::GetForegroundWindow();
// Retrieve template ID
UINT nResourceId = GetWindowLong(hwndForeGround, GWL_ID);
if (nResourceId != myModalTemplateId )
   return false;
```

or

```
CWnd *pModal = pMainFrame_->GetForegroundWindow();
  // Retrieve template ID
  UINT nResourceId = GetWindowLong(pModal->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_ID);
  if (nResourceId != myModalTemplateId )
     return false;
```

None of these code snippet worked...
The last solution I have thought was to make all my CDialog classes inherits from a custom class and register all opened CDialog, but it is a bit invasive...
Is there an "elegant" means to do that ?

Thank for reading,
Lucas.

Comment: Faking input using `SendMessage`/`PostMessage` is the wrong approach. When doing this for unit testing, you might as well not test anything. You are creating scenarios that **never** happen in the application's regular use, and you aren't testing real input paths. Like all other unit testing frameworks, you should be using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but my idea was not only to do UI test but also to do load test. I mean generate a lot of fake user action in order to check if the software is able to deal with huge user actions. Using this way I am able to generate random test scenarios...

Comment: A user probably cannot generate input as fast as UI Automation. Either way, [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (applies to mouse input as well).